# Python Entries List

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a log in page for a piece of software for University work and am struggling with Tkinter Entries.

I want to create Entries in a neat, yet efficient manner so opted for using a function to do so, but this would remove the possibility of naming variables.

How could I use the code I have to then return the values of the 'username' and 'password' entry fields once the login button is pressed?

```
    def create_widget(self, cont, args):
        if(args[0] == 'Button'):
            self.create_button(cont, args)
        elif(args[0] == 'Entry'):
            self.create_entry(args)
        elif(args[0] == 'CheckBox'):
            self.create_checkbox(args)
        elif(args[0] == 'Label'):
            self.create_label(args)
        else:
            print("Invalid Argument while creating Widget")

    def create_entry(self, args):
        if(args[4] == True):
            entry = tk.Entry(self, font=FONT, width=args[1])
            entry.place(x=args[2],y=args[3])
        else:
            entry = tk.Entry(self, font=FONT, width=args[1], show = '*')
            entry.place(x=args[2],y=args[3])

    self.create_widget(controller, ["Entry", 21, 135, 30, True])
    self.create_widget(controller, ["Entry", 21, 135, 60, False])
```

Comment: Any other improvements/suggestions would be greatly appreciated as this part of my Uni Course Work. As I said, I am pretty new to Python, so please use nothing too technical without explaining it.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Please fix syntax and typo errors in your code and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, I don't see any syntax/typo errors myself but as I said, I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure. I'll remove the full code, though usually people ask to see it.

Comment: Do not remove your code snippets but narrow those down in order to (1) reduce your code to the needed minimum, (2) make it easier to get help and (3) narrow down to which functions you really need resp. (4) which functions you do not need or (5) might lead to undesired behavior.

Comment: Is this better? Edited question intro and code snippet.

Comment: If you need to create multiple widgets then do so as a list or dictionary with a for loop.

Comment: I understand how to store data in lists etc, but how can I declare a name for the stored data for each entry initialized and still be able to call them later for functions such as entry.get() etc.

Comment: If you have a list of Entry objects you can get the first one's text for example calling `ent_lst[0].get()`.

Comment: Ok sorry, I don't want to be spoonfed but I've only ever used lists for bits of data and haven't a clue how to put objects in them, could you send me something to look at for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your `create_*` functions return the object that is created, which you can store in a dictionary or list.

```
def create_entry(self, args):
    ... 
    entry = tk.Entry(...)
    ...
    return entry

def create_widget(self, cont, args):
    ...
    elif(args[0] == 'Entry'):
        widget = self.create_entry(...)
    ...
    return widget
```

You could then use the above like this:

```
widgets = {
    "username": self.create_widget(...),
    "password": self.create_widget(...)
}
```

To retrieve the values:

```
username = widgets["username"].get()
password = widgets["password"].get()
```

Comment: Editted answer to show what happened once I did this.

Comment: Did I really just miss the commas... Sorry dude, thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Below example will update the label's text with the 2nd entry field's text when the button is pressed:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text="This text will get updated once the button is pressed")
lbl.pack()

entries = list()

num_of_entries = 3

for i in range(num_of_entries):
    entries.append(tk.Entry(root))
    entries[i].pack()

def update():
    lbl['text'] = entries[1].get()

tk.Button(root, text="Update", command=update).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I thought of something like this, but would that not require me to have a variable name for each entry, which I did not do because next will be a registration page with 5+ fields, and I thought creating widgets this way would like neater than defining every variable line by line.
Is this not the better way? I am pretty new to Python and am really bad at using Classes so trying to find a way to better incorporate Classes and functions in to my code.

Comment: @Ayden I don't understand, your problem is rather with creating multiple entries?

Comment: So I used a function "create_entry", to be called to create multiple entries. But this will not allow me to recall variable names in future as they were all initialized as "Entry".